# Spring AMQP convertSendAndReceive VS sendAndReceive

Tags: jwt, spring-amqp

I have a project where I send through AMQP a message with a signed JSON object. On the server side I have the following:

```
public class MyServerHandler implements MessageListener{
...
   @Override
   public void onMessage(Message msg) 
   {
        String _payload = new String(msg.getBody(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.out.println(_payload);
        ...
```

Now, if I use the method **convertSendAndReceive** like this:

```
String msg = ...deo // JSON object (String)
Object response = getRabbitOperations().convertSendAndReceive(_myExchange, _myRoutingKey, msg,
                new MessagePostProcessor() 
                {
                    public Message postProcessMessage(Message message) throws AmqpException 
                    {
                        message.getMessageProperties().setDeliveryMode(MessageDeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
                        message.getMessageProperties().setRedelivered(false);
                        message.getMessageProperties().setUserId(_myUser);
                        message.getMessageProperties().setType(_myType);
                        return message;
                    }
                }
        );
```

When I get the contents of the AMQP message I get the character string sent but in quotation marks:

```
String _payload = new String(msg.getBody(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
System.out.println(_payload);

"eyJ4NWMiOlsiTUlJRHV6Q0NBcU9nQXdJQkFnSUNDMEV3RFFZSktvWklodmNOQVFFR....."
```

But if I use the **sendAndReceive** method, I don't get quotation marks:

```
MessageProperties mp = new MessageProperties();
mp.setDeliveryMode(MessageDeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
mp.setRedelivered(false);
mp.setUserId(_myUser);
mp.setType(_myType);
Message _m = new Message(msg.getBytes(), mp);
Object _response = getRabbitOperations().sendAndReceive(_myExchange, _myRoutingKey, _m);
```

On the server side I get(with the same code):

```
eyJ4NWMiOlsiTUlJRHV6Q0NBcU9nQXdJQkFnSUNDMEV3RFFZSktvWklodmNOQVFFR.....
```

Why is that? Can I change it to work the same way? And which would be the right one?
Thank you

Comment: You need to show the rest of your configuration; it appears you have mismatch message converters on the sending and receiving side.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `sendAndReceive` that it deals with message directly and bypasses `MessageConverter`. According to your quotation experience it looks like there is a JSON converter. 
You can use `SimpleMessageConverter`. But that doesn't matter really: if you want clear `byte[]` to send, just do the same `msg.getBytes()` for the `convertSendAndReceive`.

Comment: Thank you Artem. Yes, I have a JSON converter:@Bean 
 public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() 
 {
  RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(simpleRoutingConnectionFactory());
  template.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter()); But I need it (at least for the moment). If I use msg.getBytes() the received message is not the same as the sent one, so for now the solution is to remove those quotes on the server once the message is received.